# Is it possible for a hacker to spoof the internet time, or any HTTP or HTTPs response?

Tags: internet, spoofing

I want to create an application that self-destruct after a certain date ( say: 2022 January 1st).

For this I will get [the time from the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9830462/3834), and then compare it with the given date, and if the date is expired, then the application will not start.

But is there anyway for a hacker to continue to use the application after that certain date, by writing a tool to successfully return a false time when my application checks for the internet time?

Comment: If you cannot trust the computer where you run that program on you cannot guarantee it deletes anything at all. Also if you use a form of network connection you need to defend against person in the middle attacks. This does only work if the validation can be trusted (I.e. nobody exchanges your certificate check against another).

Comment: A hacker can do everything if they have physical access to the machine the application runs in

Comment: Please ask your real question: How can I create an application that only starts before a given date? It would be off-topic here, but probably on-topic (and may be a duplicate) on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Marcel your question is an interesting one and I might ask it on SO. But as far as the current question stands, it is on-topic here I believe

Comment: @Graviton Yes, the core part is of course on-topic here. The first paragraph however sounds like a tool/feature/implementation detail request, which I encourage you to reword.